# SpringDoc OpenAPI using "springdoc-openapi-ui" vs "springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, springdoc, springdoc-ui

Trying to implement spring doc for my microservices at the Spring Cloud gateway level.

Came across these two dependencies. Want to know what is the difference between

```
"springdoc-openapi-ui" vs "springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core"
```

and

```
"springdoc-openapi-ui" vs "springdoc-openapi-ui"
```

Which dependency to prefer?

Answer (score 4):

Upon checking the source code of `springdoc-openapi-ui`
It has a maven dependency on

```
<!-- springdoc-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

`springdoc-openapi-ui`  gives both swaggerUI and json API (along with yaml format).
`springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core` will only provide the swagger api alone.

Comment: Regarding `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api` the official documentations says (quote, emphasys mine): "This dependency is relevant if you want to generate the OpenAPI description **without using the swagger-ui**." Source: https://springdoc.org/#spring-webmvc-support

Comment: This answer is also useful: [Spring Boot 3 springdoc-openapi-ui doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74701779/814702).