# Spring Boot 3 springdoc-openapi-ui doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add swagger-ui (OpenAPI 3.0) to a Spring Boot v3 application.

I've added the openapi-ui maven dependency, and it should work as per the documentation.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

But apparently, it still doesn't work and localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html returns an 404 error.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: If the solutions below does not solve the problem, you might check my answer on **[How to run Swagger 3 on Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614369/how-to-run-swagger-3-on-spring-boot-3)**

Answer (score 131, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> For **spring-boot 3** support, make sure you use **springdoc-openapi v2**

[What is the compatibility matrix of springdoc-openapi with spring-boot?](https://springdoc.org/#what-is-the-compatibility-matrix-of-springdoc-openapi-with-spring-boot)

> For the integration between spring-boot and swagger-ui, add the
> library to the list of your project dependencies (No additional
> configuration is needed)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

> This will automatically deploy swagger-ui to a spring-boot
> application:
>
> Documentation will be available in HTML format, using the official
> swagger-ui jars
>
> The Swagger UI page will then be available at
> `http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html` and the OpenAPI
> description will be available at the following url for json format:
> `http://server:port/context-path/v3/api-docs`

```
server: The server name or IP

port: The server port

context-path: The context path of the application

Documentation can be available in yaml format as well, on the following path : /v3/api-docs.yaml
```

---

#### Please note that modules have been renamed:

https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springdoc-v1

[image]

Comment: This kind of weird. Accoding to documentation https://springdoc.org/ in intoduction section it states. Library supports OpenAPI 3, Spring-boot (v1, v2 and v3) which is apparently not truth. In spring boot 3 environment something changes in spring factories and springdoc beans are not instantiated at all.

Comment: Still not working for me even with Spring Boot 3 and the right dependencies.

Comment: Make sure you replace the springdoc-openapi-ui dependency by the springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui one. If you use both of them the application will not start

Comment: Don't be a chump like me - use the access :  
_http://server:port/swagger-ui/index.html_  
.  
After upgrading I kept putting in <context-path>  :  
  _http://server:port/<contextpath>/swagger-ui/index.html_  
.  
Wasted about half a day on that.

Comment: @MarkO'Donohue I'm probably having the same problem you had, I can't seem to make it work, I commented out all my config and I'm trying to access it via http://localhost:8080/context-path/swagger-ui.html, Am I missing something?

Answer (score 21):

I completely agreed with @JCompetence. Please note that
**springdoc-openapi-ui** now changed to **springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui**
from spring boot 3.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please try this. If you want to find more info, please check the official link:
https://springdoc.org/v2/#features

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore. Try it without the /v2

Answer (score 11):

For me it helped, just changed the dependency

```
   implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.11'
```

to

```
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.0.0'
```

or

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to [use springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/)

```yaml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

for kotlin you must add one dependency more

```yaml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then add `@OpenAPIDefinition on your main class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition
class MyApplication {
}
```

Comment: There's no @OpenAPIDefinition

Answer (score 6):

`springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` doesn't work with `spring-boot-starter-webflux`
until you include `spring-boot-starter-web`.
If you include spring security then it is dead.

Comment: For webflux use:::

   
springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui

Answer (score 4):

Just an add-on if your application have spring security enabled !!
Then you will need to whitelist swagger-endpoint to not use authentication

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/v3/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });

return httpSecurity.build();
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else struggling with this using webflux on Gradle, I managed to get a barebones project working that provides access to the UI and api-docs.
For me you needed this line in the plugins section

```
id 'java-library'
```

(along with the spring boot framework plugin)

EDIT: It seems like the above line is not necessary? Unsure, but if you're trying this, it should also work without java-library.

and you (should) only need these two dependencies

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:3.1.4'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.1.0'
```

Gradle version that I used is 8.3

If you're able to hit

```
http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
```

Then that's a good sign.

You can find an example project I made below
https://github.com/AlbertSnows/spring-boot-webflux-openapi

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. How did you find out anyway? Maybe I did not include in the google search that I am using webflux :/

Comment: @ImranFaruqi I spent multiple days on it. I only fixed it after stumbling across the repo my repo is forked from. Here's a comment I left on said repo after finding it -> https://github.com/hendisantika/spring-boot-webflux-openapi/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

**Maven plugin to generate (Java) code from OpenApi spec (.yml files)**

Generator “spring” supports Jakarta namespace

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <configOptions>
            ...
            **<useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>**
        </configOptions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Generator “java” (to generate a client) doesn’t support Jakarta namespace yet.
So use the Eclipse Transformer plugin (Javax dependencies need provided scope!)

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>
        <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
           <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>
         </rules>
       </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jakarta-ee</id>
                <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <artifact>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    </artifact>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add this annotation to your SpringBootApp main class:
@OpenAPIDefinition

```
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition
class MyApplication
```

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Security support use the Below dependency

```
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.1.0")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0")
```

from https://springdoc.org/v2/#migrating-from-springfox

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and solved it by changing the following dependency

from : `implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15'`

to : `implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.0.0'`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add below dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
     <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Step 2: Add below 2 lines of code in SecurityConfiguration

```
.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/v3/api-docs/**")).permitAll()
```

Now it will work on this url :

```
base-url/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please have in mind this compatibility matrix for spring boot:

[Compatibility matrix](https://springdoc.org/#what-is-the-compatibility-matrix-of-springdoc-openapi-with-spring-boot)

**I would also advice that you delete the cookies of your browser for the host you are trying to access swagger on!**

Answer (score 0):

in my case, you have to add below lines in application.yml:
`springdoc: api-docs: path: /api-docs swagger-ui: path: /swagger-ui.html enabled: true`