# Springfox and Springboot compatibility

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

Which version of springfox is compatible with springboot 3.0.2

I have trying to incorporate springfox 3 into springboot 3. Although my console shows no error, the swagger ui is not appearing. But as i changed my springboot version to 2.7.8, swagger is working. So i want to know which version of springfox swagger will be compatible with springboot 3.0.2, as my project requires that version of spring boot

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [Why is Swagger UI not working in Spring Boot 3.0 version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74876051/113116)

Answer (score 1):

Spring fox is not maintained and will not support springboot 3.x. You can use springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.

```
 implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0'
```

https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html

Above link will guide for the migration from springfox to springdoc.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with springfox 2 while working with springboot(2.2 ->2.7).
Now i find it more reliable to use OpenApi :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

also you can try using swagger from yahoo(elide) :

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.yahoo.elide</groupId>
                <artifactId>elide-swagger</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
```