# Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present how to solve this in springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I am using this dependency for implementing swagger but its not working both swagger and springboot are version 3

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

the swagger is is showing error

`Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present`

has springboot has inbuild servlet then why its asking

Comment: Spring Boot 3 supports JakartaEE **not** JavaEE.

Comment: yes but i want to use swagger in my project so while using swagger its showing that particular error so what should i do to implement swagger

Comment: You cannot use that version of swagger with spring boot 3.

Comment: so through what can i replace to implement in spring boot 3

Comment: By using a version that uses JakartaEE and not JavaEE, as (kind of hinted at) mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: swagger does'nt support jakartaEE

Comment: And there you have your solution, don't use swagger. Use OpenAPI (which appears the commonly accepted replacement).

Comment: ok I will try it thankyou can u share the proper version of dependency which would work for spring boot 3

Answer (score 1):

There is a long explanation what happened to springfox [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876156/175554), shortly  with Spring boot 3 we can use **springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui** which will bring swagger-ui, below you can find the full pom.xml and for full working example please check [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/swagger-boot3-graalvm)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <name>demo</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Spring boot 3 with "record" and "swagger ui" http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error and for me it worked using the OpenApi:

**pom.xml**:

```
    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Swagger END -->
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java** (add this line if you are using springboot security):

```
     .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
```

Then I went to the link: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

I didn't need to add any other configurations.

Like it was mentioned by ozkanpakdil this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876051/why-swagger-ui-is-not-working-in-spring-boot-3-0-version/74876156#74876156) also helped have a better understanding why the SpringFox was not working.

Thank you!