Springfox 2.8 nor 3.0 working in a Spring Boot 2.7 project
We cant find a way to get Swagger working with any of our Spring Boot 2.7 applications.
We have tried every config variation we can find on the web, none work so far. Below are examples of the configs and the errors they produce.
Any suggestions welcome.
This is the main error we get:
Parameter 0 of constructor in springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.BasePathAwareServicesProvider required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration' in your configuration.

Someone else had this issue here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3528  The only solution provided was to remove spring-boot-starter-data-rest.  This does appear in the effective pom, but we dont include it in any pom, so we dont know where it comes from or how to remove it.
This is the dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"!prod && swagger"})
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("OUR SERVICE ")
                .description("Our service endpoints")
                .version("mixed")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
        List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
        return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));

    }
}

application.yml:
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8080}
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jpa:
      ...          
  datasource:

  profiles:
    active: ${ENV:stg}
  config:
    import:
      - classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.yml


We also tried this but it didn't make a difference:
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}

Also tried using older dependecies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

This gives same error.

I belive that your question is quite similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876051/why-swagger-ui-is-not-working-in-spring-boot-3-0-version

Thanks Nguyen.  That link is for issues using Spring Boot 3.0.  We are still using  boot 2.7 and java 8 unfortunately.

The partial solution was to remove all the swagger related config and dependencies, and simply add this on its own:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

1.8 is the recommend version for spring boot 2.x
See: https://springdoc.org/v1/
The reason this is not the full solution is that swagger supports not exposing the api docs on our public facing prod environments, but open-api doesnt have this option.  This is a security issue.

It seems is related to compatibility between Spring Boot 2.7 and the version of Springfox you're using. Springfox 3.0.0 has known compatibility issues with certain versions of Spring Boot, particularly when it comes to spring-boot-starter-data-rest.
The solution will be
Upgrade to Springdoc OpenAPI:
NoClassDefFoundError with Open API with Spring Boot 3
If switching to Springdoc is not an option, you can try the following workaround:
Exclude spring-boot-starter-data-rest from Springfox: Modify the springfox-boot-starter dependency to exclude the conflicting starter:
Manually define RepositoryRestConfiguration Bean: If you need to keep spring-boot-starter-data-rest, define a RepositoryRestConfiguration bean manually:
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestConfig {

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration() {
        return new RepositoryRestConfiguration();
    }
}
Up

date Springfox Configuration: Ensure that your Swagger configuration is fully compatible with Spring Boot 2.7:
Remove the @EnableSwagger2 annotation:
This is no longer needed with Springfox 3.x and might cause issues.
Replace @EnableWebMvc with @EnableWebMvc (Spring 5) if necessary, but it's often better to avoid enabling Web MVC unless required by your application.
