# Spring Boot + Swagger 2 not working (404)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I`m  trying to add some API documentation to my web project (swagger-ui). However it gives me 404 on
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
and
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

Here is my Maven config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.racoonsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>mm-gate</artifactId>
    <name>MMGate</name>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </parent>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>racoonsoft-repository</id>
            <url>http://racoonsoft.ru:8081/artifactory/racoonsoft/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Retrofit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-rxjava3</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava3/rxjava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava3</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-rxjava3</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/logging-interceptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.racoonsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>racoon-utils</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.racoonsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-template</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>spring-boot-crud</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Swagger settings:

```java
@Configuration
public class SwaggerSettings {

    @Bean
    public Docket configApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Other configurations:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    protected AuthService authService;
    @Autowired
    protected AdminInterceptor adminInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/assets");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new GateAuthInterceptor(authService)).addPathPatterns("/gate/**");
        registry.addInterceptor(adminInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/admin/**");
    }
}
```

I use OpenJDK 19 (Oracle).

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: springfox is dead([2020](https://github.com/springfox/springfox)) ... Long live [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/)!

Answer (score 0):

With `SpringBoot3` its recommended to use **org.springdoc**. As suggested in comments

Add below dependency in your pom.xml, Update project do **mvn clean install** & if using spring-security whiltelist swagger-endpoint to not use authentication, Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75752381/16769477) answer for the same.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```