# Swagger 3 getting Whitelabel Error Page in SpringBoot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, backend, swagger-ui

I am making API in Springboot 3. When I added this [dependency](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-swagger-3/) , I am getting whitelabel error page at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html or other links. I also added @EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.springdoc"})
@SpringBootApplication annotation but they didn't solve my problem.

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>codding</groupId>
    <artifactId>userDataBase</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>userDataBase</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Application java file:

```
package coding.userDataBase;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UserDataBaseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserDataBaseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

How can I solve this swagger 3 in springboot 3 getting whitelabel error. Thanks for everyone btw.

Comment: Hope this link helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701738/spring-boot-3-springdoc-openapi-ui-doesnt-work

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem. I am still getting 404 error

Comment: I solved the problem. "springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api" it must be "springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui"

Comment: Springfox and Springdoc are incompatible. You might need to remove the Springfox dependency and keep just Springdoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove other swagger dependencies from pom.xml and use this instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```