# Spring Boot 3 springdoc-openapi Failed to load remote configuration

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

I have included the swagger for my current project, which is using the spring version 3.1.2.

I have added the following dependencies in the pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Inside the application.yml this configuration:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs
    enabled: true
```

Inside my SpringBootApp main class l added the @OpenAPIDefinition annotation

When l am running the application and l go to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html l got this message

[image]

Inside the application l got the message:

`WARN 35407 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound No mapping for GET /v3/api-docs/swagger-config`

l have followed the instructions in [this tutorial](https://springdoc.org/#how-do-i-migrate-to-openapi-3-with-springdoc-openapi), and see similars problems like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701738/spring-boot-3-springdoc-openapi-ui-doesnt-work), but still is not working.

Someone knows what l am doing wrong.

I want to see the swagger working properly, but is not working as expected.

I have read the whole tutorial [example](https://springdoc.org/#how-do-i-migrate-to-openapi-3-with-springdoc-openapi) but l am not able to make it works.